# O365 - Changing external sharing policy on folder and not site level

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, external-sharing

I need to change the sharing policy on the folder level on the SharePoint sites, and not only the site level, is this possible in any way, with Powershell.

I have been looking through the documentation but have not had any luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, there is no folder level external sharing settings you can configure. It only works on tenant level and site level. You may need to consider another approach like making a unique permission on that folder.